# How do I resolve the "untrusted domain" authentification error connecting to SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, authentication, kerberos

I have a .Net app that connects to SQL using the Systen.Data.SqlClient assembly. Up until recently it has been working fine during development and also on my test network using test logins. Recently I've suddenly started getting the error on the test network:

SQL State: 28000
SQL Server Error: 18452
Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.

If I login on the client machine as a domain admin I can connect with no problem. If I login on the client with another AD account, which is not a domain admin, I get this error. I've run the Kerberos Configuration Manager and fixed the SPNs (although I don't fully understand the meaning of that) and the error still occurs after both machines have restarted, but only for the non domain admin login.

The error message looks to me that it should be associated with the machine, not the user!? The code that  is connecting looks like this:

```
cCon = String.Format("Server={0};Database={1};Trusted_Connection=Yes;", cServer, cDatabase)
moSqlCon = New SqlConnection(cCon)
moSqlCon.Open()
If moSqlCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
    mbConnected = True
End If
```

I've also tried logging in as both users and creating an ODBC connection. Again the domain admin succeeds and the non-domain admin fails with the same error. What else can I try?

Comment: What user is the app running as? Is it running as the logged in user, or as SYSTEM or NETWORK SERVICE? If the latter, that means the machine probably had it's machine account removed from AD.

Comment: @Steve Thanks for replying. The SQL Server service is running under a local account sql.service made for the purpose, but not SYSTEM or NETWORK. The connection succeeds from the client when connecting as a domain admin, but fails using a normal non-domain admin AD account (both of which have been given the sysadmin role within the SQL server).

Comment: @Steve To clarify, The client app is running under the credentials of the test user, which is an AD account and doesn't work resulting in the error above. However, when I log in as myself (domain admin), it does succeed. Am wondering if it is to do with the fact that the SQL service is running under a local account and not an AD account. However, temporarily given the test account domain admin rights and it still cannot connect. Same error.